# Factoring custom grammar rules for integers and lists in Coq custom entries

Tags: coq, notation

Is there a nice way to use custom entries to parse the following grammar?  ("nice" meaning ~ "without massive duplication" and ~ "without needing to resort to separate printing and parsing notations and Ltac)

```
slicing              := constr '.[' slice_list ']'

slice_list           := '…' | slice_expr | slice_list ',' slice_expr

slice_expr           := single_slice_expr | slice_expr_with_step | slice_expr_no_step
slice_expr_no_step   := ':' | INT ':' | ':' INT | INT ':' INT
slice_expr_with_step := slice_expr_no_step ':' INT
single_slice_expr    := 'None' | INT
```

(where `INT` is parsed according to `Number Notation`, which for now I'm using `constr%uint63` for)

(Note that my lists are left-associative, by design; they will be parsed to snoc-lists.)

I cannot seem to find a way to get the `INT` from `single_slice_expr` to factor with the leading `INT`s from the other alternatives of `slice_expr` (and to make it trickier the `'None'` literal needs to be at level 0 to avoiding making `None` a keyword).

So far I have

```ml
(* -*- coding: utf-8 -*- *)
From Coq Require Import Sint63 Uint63.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Set Boolean Equality Schemes.
Set Decidable Equality Schemes.

#[local] Coercion is_true : bool >-> Sortclass.
Record Slice I := { start : option I ; stop : option I ; step : option I }.

Fixpoint radd (n m : nat) {struct m} : nat
  := match m with
     | 0 => n
     | S p => S (radd n p)
     end.
Fixpoint rsub (n m : nat) {struct m} : nat
  := match m, n with
     | 0, n => n
     | S p, S k => rsub k p
     | S p, 0 => 0
     end.

Reserved Infix "+'" (at level 48, left associativity).
Reserved Infix "-'" (at level 50, left associativity).
Module Export Notations.
  Infix "+'" := radd : nat_scope.
  Infix "-'" := rsub : nat_scope.
End Notations.

Definition Rank := nat.
Definition IndexType := int.
Inductive SliceIndexType : Rank -> Rank -> Type :=
| slice_index (s : Slice IndexType) : SliceIndexType 1 1
| broadcast_one_index : SliceIndexType 0 1
| single_index (i : IndexType) : SliceIndexType 1 0
.

#[export] Set Warnings Append "-uniform-inheritance,-ambiguous-paths".
#[global] Set Warnings Append "-uniform-inheritance,-ambiguous-paths".
#[global] Coercion slice_index : Slice >-> SliceIndexType.
#[export] Set Warnings Append "uniform-inheritance,ambiguous-paths".
#[global] Set Warnings Append "uniform-inheritance,ambiguous-paths".
#[global] Coercion single_index : IndexType >-> SliceIndexType.
#[global] Coercion inject_int (x : int) : IndexType := x.

Inductive SliceIndex : Rank (* input *) -> Rank (* output *) -> Type :=
| nil : SliceIndex 0 0
| elipsis {r} : SliceIndex r r
| snoc {ris ros ri ro} : SliceIndex ris ros -> SliceIndexType ri ro -> SliceIndex (ris +' ri) (ros +' ro).


Declare Custom Entry fancy_slice.
Declare Custom Entry less_fancy_slice.
Notation ":" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ None None None)) (in custom fancy_slice at level 1).
(* N.B. 35 is the minimum level for negative integers to parse *)
Notation "start : stop : step" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ (Some start%sint63) (Some stop%sint63) (Some step%sint63))) (in custom fancy_slice at level 2, start constr at level 35, stop constr at level 35, step constr at level 35, format "start : stop : step").
Notation "start :: step" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ (Some start%sint63) None (Some step%sint63))) (in custom fancy_slice at level 2, start constr at level 35, step constr at level 35, format "start :: step").
Notation "start : : step" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ (Some start%sint63) None (Some step%sint63))) (in custom fancy_slice at level 2, start constr at level 35, step constr at level 35, format "start : : step").
Notation "start :: step" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ (Some start%sint63) None (Some step%sint63))) (in custom fancy_slice at level 2, start constr at level 35, step constr at level 35, format "start :: step").
Notation ": stop : step" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ None (Some stop%sint63) (Some step%sint63))) (in custom fancy_slice at level 1, stop constr at level 35, step constr at level 35, format ": stop : step").
Notation ": : step" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ None None (Some step%sint63))) (in custom fancy_slice at level 1, step constr at level 35, format ": : step").
Notation ":: step" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ None None (Some step%sint63))) (in custom fancy_slice at level 1, step constr at level 35, format ":: step").
Notation "start : stop" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ (Some start%sint63) (Some stop%sint63) None)) (in custom fancy_slice at level 2, start constr at level 35, stop constr at level 35, format "start : stop").
Notation "start :" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ (Some start%sint63) None None)) (in custom fancy_slice at level 2, start constr at level 35, format "start :").
Notation ": stop" := (slice_index (@Build_Slice _ None (Some stop%sint63) None)) (in custom fancy_slice at level 1, stop constr at level 35, format ": stop").
Notation "'None'" := broadcast_one_index (in custom less_fancy_slice at level 0). (* need to avoid breaking Datatypes.None *)
Notation "x" := x%sint63 (in custom less_fancy_slice at level 0, x constr at level 55).
Notation "x" := x (in custom fancy_slice at level 1, x custom less_fancy_slice at level 0).
Notation "'None'" := broadcast_one_index (in custom fancy_slice at level 0). (* need to avoid breaking Datatypes.None *)

Declare Scope tensor_scope.
Delimit Scope tensor_scope with tensor.

Notation "t .[ x , .. , y ]"
  := (t%tensor (snoc .. (snoc nil x) .. y))
       (at level 2, x custom fancy_slice at level 60, y custom fancy_slice at level 60, left associativity, format "t .[ x ,  .. ,  y ]")
    : tensor_scope.
Notation "t .[ … , x , .. , y ]"
  := (t%tensor (snoc .. (snoc elipsis x) .. y))
       (at level 2, x custom fancy_slice at level 60, y custom fancy_slice at level 60, left associativity, format "t .[ … ,  x ,  .. ,  y ]")
    : tensor_scope.

Open Scope tensor_scope.
Eval cbn in  _.[0:1:1].
Eval cbn in  _.[1:-1:1].
Eval cbn in  _.[1:-1:1,1:-1:1].
Eval cbn in  _.[1:-1].
Eval cbn in  _.[:-1].
Eval cbn in  _.[1:].
Eval cbn in  _.[1::1].
Eval cbn in  _.[1::1,:1].
Eval cbn in  _.[1::1,1:].
Eval cbn in  _.[:].
Eval cbn in  _.[::1].
Eval cbn in  _.[:1].
Eval cbn in  _.[:1].
Eval cbn in  _.[1]. (* Error: Syntax error: '::' or ':' expected after [term level 35] (in [custom:fancy_slice]). *)
Eval cbn in  _.[None].
Eval cbn in  _.[1::1,1].
Eval cbn in  _.[1:-1:1, None, 0].
Eval cbn in  _.[:, None, 0].
Eval cbn in  _.[:1, None, 0].
Eval cbn in  _.[:-1:1, None, 0].
```

(Cross-posted [from Zulip](https://coq.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/237977-Coq-users/topic/Custom.20entries.20and.20grammar.20factoring/near/380143140))